# How to wait for http get request to finish?

Tags: angularjs, http

```
var count = 0;
getColumns($scope);
function getColumns(tmp) {
    EmpApi.getExtraColumns().success(function (cols) {
        $scope.cols = cols;
        count = Object.keys($scope.cols).length;
        console.log(count);     

    }).error(function (error) {
        $scope.status = "unable to load columns";
    })
}
console.log(count);
```

I am trying to update my count variable with the code above. It is in a controller. In getExtraColumns function console.log prints the right value of count. but the second count in the outer scope still prints 0. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Simply… don't. Don't try to print the value in the outer scope.

Comment: @deceze but I need to use it

Comment: You don't need to use it *there*. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667087/476.